# Can't make Admob App Open Ads to appear on app launch

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I'm trying to implement Admob App Open Ads and did exactly what it says on Admob page. But ad doesn't open on app launch but it opens on if app minimized to background and bring back to foreground. I think this is the default Google implementation of app open ads. But I want to make app appear on app launch. Can you help me?

There is 2 classes that makes app open ads work. MyApplication and AppOpenManager classes.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static AppOpenManager appOpenManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MobileAds.initialize(
                this,
                initializationStatus -> {});

        appOpenManager = new AppOpenManager(this);

    }
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Prefetches App Open Ads.
 */
public class AppOpenManager implements LifecycleObserver,Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AppOpenManager";
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-7500195269906423/9767523313";
    private AppOpenAd appOpenAd = null;
    private Activity currentActivity;
    private AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback loadCallback;
    private final MyApplication myApplication;
    private static boolean isShowingAd = false;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public AppOpenManager(MyApplication myApplication) {
        this.myApplication = myApplication;
        this.myApplication.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }

    /** LifecycleObserver methods */
    @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
    public void onStart() {
        showAdIfAvailable();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
    }


    /** Shows the ad if one isn't already showing. */
    public void showAdIfAvailable() {
        // Only show ad if there is not already an app open ad currently showing
        // and an ad is available.
        if (!isShowingAd && isAdAvailable()) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");

            FullScreenContentCallback fullScreenContentCallback =
                    new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                            AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = null;
                            isShowingAd = false;
                            fetchAd();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            isShowingAd = true;
                        }
                    };

            appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(fullScreenContentCallback);
            appOpenAd.show(currentActivity);

        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can not show ad.");
            fetchAd();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Request an ad
     */
    public void fetchAd() {
        // Have unused ad, no need to fetch another.
        if (isAdAvailable()) {
            return;
        }

        loadCallback =
                new AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {
                    /**
                     * Called when an app open ad has loaded.
                     *
                     * @param ad the loaded app open ad.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(AppOpenAd ad) {
                        AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = ad;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Called when an app open ad has failed to load.
                     *
                     * @param loadAdError the error.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                    }

                };
        AdRequest request = getAdRequest();
        AppOpenAd.load(
                myApplication, AD_UNIT_ID, request,
                AppOpenAd.APP_OPEN_AD_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, loadCallback);

    }

    /**
     * Creates and returns ad request.
     */
    private AdRequest getAdRequest() {
        return new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    }

    /**
     * Utility method that checks if ad exists and can be shown.
     */
    public boolean isAdAvailable() {
        return appOpenAd != null;
    }

    /** ActivityLifecycleCallback methods */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: This `appOpenAd.show(currentActivity);` should be inside `onAdLoaded` if you want to show as soon as it is loaded or check out his library: https://github.com/ItzNotABug/AppOpenAdManager.

Comment: I tried both options you suggested but both of them gives me the exact thing I already have. Ad only shows when it comes to foreground.

Comment: Thank you ,I made it work now. I added "showAdOnFirstColdStart= true" to parameters and it works now (Almost works as I wanted to ad loads like in 3-5 seconds but it shows on initial launch at least). Why didn't you make it true on default? Also your test id is for interstatial ads if it matters I don't know but thank you for this library. And your answer also.

Comment: Thanks for the Ad Unit catch!

Comment: How can i make it so app would flow from SplashActivity to MainActivity in the launch only when user touches the "Continue to App" Button?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your AppOpenManager

```
    import android.app.Activity
    import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.Event.ON_START
    import android.app.Application
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.content.Context
    import android.util.Log
    import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver
    import androidx.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent
    import androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdError
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.FullScreenContentCallback
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.appopen.AppOpenAd
    import java.util.*
    
    class AppOpenManager (private var myApplication: MyApplication) : LifecycleObserver,Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
        companion object {
            private const val LOG_TAG = "AppOpenManager"
            private const val AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294"
        }
        private var appOpenAd: AppOpenAd? = null
        private lateinit var loadCallback: AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback
        private var currentActivity : Activity? = null
        private var isShowingAd : Boolean = false
        private var loadTime:Long = 0
        private var temp = 0
    init{
        this.myApplication.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
    fun onStart() {
        showAdIfAvailable()
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart")
    }

    fun showAdIfAvailable() {
        // Only show ad if there is not already an app open ad currently showing
        // and an ad is available.
        if (!isShowingAd && isAdAvailable())
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.")
            val fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
                override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                    this@AppOpenManager.appOpenAd = null
                    isShowingAd = false
                    fetchAd()
                }
                override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError) {}
                override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    isShowingAd = true
                }
            }
            appOpenAd?.show(currentActivity, fullScreenContentCallback)
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can not show ad.")
            fetchAd()
        }
    }
    /** Request an ad */
    fun fetchAd() {
        // We will implement this below.
        if (isAdAvailable()) {
            return
        }
        loadCallback = object:AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {
            /**
             * Called when an app open ad has loaded.
             *
             * @param ad the loaded app open ad.
             */
            override fun onAppOpenAdLoaded(ad:AppOpenAd) {

                this@AppOpenManager.appOpenAd = ad
                this@AppOpenManager.loadTime = (Date()).getTime()

                val fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
                    override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                        // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                        this@AppOpenManager.appOpenAd = null
                        isShowingAd = false
                        fetchAd()
                    }
                    override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError) {}
                    override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                        isShowingAd = true
                    }
                }
                if(temp==0)
                {
                    appOpenAd?.show(currentActivity, fullScreenContentCallback)
                    temp=1
                }
            }
            /**
             * Called when an app open ad has failed to load.
             *
             * @param loadAdError the error.
             */
            override fun onAppOpenAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError: LoadAdError) {
                // Handle the error.
            }
        }

        val request : AdRequest  = getAdRequest()
        AppOpenAd.load(
            myApplication, AD_UNIT_ID, request,
            AppOpenAd.APP_OPEN_AD_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, loadCallback)
    }


    /** Creates and returns ad request. */
    private fun getAdRequest():AdRequest {
        return AdRequest.Builder().build()
    }
    /** Utility method that checks if ad exists and can be shown. */
    fun isAdAvailable():Boolean {
        return appOpenAd != null && wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(4)
    }

    /** Utility method to check if ad was loaded more than n hours ago. */
    private fun wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(numHours:Long):Boolean {
        val dateDifference = (Date()).time - this.loadTime
        val numMilliSecondsPerHour:Long = 3600000
        return (dateDifference < (numMilliSecondsPerHour * numHours))
    }

    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {

    }

    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
        currentActivity = activity
    }

    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {
        currentActivity = null
    }

    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) {

    }

    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {

    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    }

    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {
        currentActivity = activity
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain it what you have changed?